# Is it correct to say "Be m a number...", instead of "Let m be a number..." in math and elsewhere?

Tags: grammaticality, mathematics

I know declaring things with 'be' is common in older texts. Is it grammatically sound using it in this context? It doesn't have to be in math, but that is where I saw it once and have been writing it ever since.

Here some more examples:

- "Be *ε* a sufficiently small positive number."
- "Assume, by way of contradiction, that *f(x)* = 0 has multiple solutions; be *a* and *b* any of two them."
- "Be *x* = 10 and *y* = 14.:
- "Be *A* the altitude and *θ* the angle of elevation."
- "Be *x*, *y* and *z* the coordinates of this vector."

Comment: "Be it ever so humble, there's no place like home" means *Even if it is* humble, not let it be. And "Let x=10" is a fixed form in math, so inventing others will make it look like an outsider wrote it.

Comment: Could you say where you saw these things? There is an older usage of the subjunctive, no longer seen today, to write "if *m* be a number..." But I've never seen "Be m a number." This looks a lot like what you'd see in French or German, though.

Comment: @YosefBaskin that doesn't however mean that "be X" can't mean "let X be."  For example, "hallowed be thy name" or "now therefore be it resolved...."

Comment: Hello. Great question, but could you please add examples of "declaring things with 'be' in older texts"?

Comment: "I know its used a lot in the Qur'an" You mean, it's used in a lot of *translations* of the Qur'an.

Comment: It's completely wrong. Anywhere you saw it is simply wrong.

Comment: There are languages where the imperative can be in other person than the 2nd, where this could work. It might have worked in English once too, but it seems native speakers can no longer understand it or distinguish it from the subjunctive. "Let x be" is the standard way to express this analytically.

Answer (score 30):

No, constructions like “**Be** *m* an integer” and others with *be* are not at all idiomatic in mathematical discourse. What you *will* find is things like “**Let** *m* **be** an integer,” “**Suppose** *m* **is** an integer,” and “**Assume** *m* **is** an integer.”

Comment: I would insert the word "modern" between "mathematical" and "discourse" in your first sentence (the construction is archaic, and was once considered acceptable---it no longer is).  (+1)

Comment: @XanderHenderson: Agreed, except that we actually put "modern" *before* "mathematical", not after it. (See https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=modern+mathematical%2Cmathematical+modern&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3 .)

Comment: @ruakh That's just me being dyslexic.  Of course, you are correct (the line break on my screen messed with my head).

Answer (score 7):

> Is it grammatically sound using it in this context?

No. Grammar guidance changes. This use of "to be" in the present subjunctive to indicate irrealis - a theoretical or possible state of an object - died out about 400 years ago, but is fossilised in some phrases, sayings, quotations, etc.

*Be ε a sufficiently small positive number -> **If** ε **is** a sufficiently small positive number

*Be x, y and z the coordinates of this vector. -> **If** x, y and z **are** the coordinates of this vector.

Religious texts and speech is a different matter, apparently deities do not speak Modern English and their acolytes mimic them.

Comment: I would not read any of the given examples as the beginning of an if/then statement.  Rather, they are assumptions, which, in normal mathematical exposition, would be more along the lines of "Let $\varepsilon$ be sufficiently small..." or "Assume that $x$, $y$, and $z$ are the coordinates...".  These are statements meant to instantiate some kind of object, not to introduce a conditional (at least, that is how it reads to my ear).

Comment: I'm sure they are an "if statement" - compare "Were I a millionaire, I would buy a palace." = "If I were a millionaire, I would buy a palace." and "Had I £1 million, I would buy a palace." = "If I had I £1 million, I would buy a palace.". That said, the OP has given no real context and Let and if carry much the same meaning.

Comment: I am conveying to you how I read that language, as a trained mathematician.  As you say, there is context missing, but all of these appear to be examples of instantiation, not conditionals.  You are free to ignore me, but your interpretation does not sound right to my mathematically trained ear.

Answer (score 6):

It's archaic, but with that in mind it is arguably correct.  Only arguably so, however: most native speakers would probably (as you see here) call it incorrect, because they aren't well versed in early modern English.  The subjunctive mood is all but gone from the present-day language.

It will certainly make your readers stumble, and that is unlikely to be your goal.  You are probably well advised to stick to the idiomatic "let X be" or "assume X is," etc.

Also, the construction "be X" meaning "whether X be true" or "even though X be true" is probably closer to most people's minds, as in the example mentioned in a comment "be it ever so humble, there's no place like home."  Reading your second example, I would think you're going in that direction, which would be wrong.

Another factor: you can read "let x = 10" as "let X equal ten," which is an idiomatic English sentence, but in the subjunctive mood it should be "be X 10" (or more obscurely "equal X 10").  Seeing "be x = 10" I'm a bit confused as to what words I should pronounce, but "be X 10" is rather cryptic.

Comment: I think it also sounds wrong because **Be** can be used in the imperative: Be of good cheer; Death, be not proud.

Comment: @AndrewLazarus Sounds like you're arguing that it sounds correct ;-) When we write "Let x be a number..." we *want* the imperative. We use "Let ... be" instead of "Be ..." specifically because there is no third-person imperative in English, and the "let" construction is as close as we can get to third-person imperative.

Comment: @Stef But imperative "let X be ten" is addressed to the reader: second person imperative of "let" in tbe sense of "allow."  When "be" is used as the second person imperative, it is an instruction to the listener to adopt some state ("be happy"), which it decidedly is not in a construction such as "be it now enacted...."

Comment: @phoog Yes? I agree that there doesn't exist a third-person imperative in English and consequently that neither "let X be 10" nor "be X 10" are third-person imperative, since there is no such thing. Other that that I am not sure I understood your comment.

Comment: Just because it was once correct, when early modern English was the spoken dialect, it doesn't mean it's correct now.

Comment: Worth noting that the equivalent probably works better in other languages, such as French ("soit").

Comment: It's totally wrong.  Archaic speech is: wrong. It was correct then and is wrong now.